# aggregation in spark Streaming from kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a stream of data from IOT devices. Each device has device id and some metrics. I need to calculate min, max, avg on those metrics across the device ID in each window of a fixed time interval. And I need to persist those min, max, avg aggregations for each above window time. If the day changes those min, max, avgs should reset to current day. This shoold happen in each in each window interval. and I need to write these valuse to a kafka stream topic in each window.

Eg: there is a stream of students IDs with their marks. I need to calculate min, max, avgs across student ID in a window. and I need to persis them in a dataframe. The calculation of min, max, avg shulud happenn in each window.and I need to write these valuse to a kafka stream topic in each window. once Day chanes the persisted values need to reset.

For This case can I use Spark structured streaming or Dstreaming. if so please let me know the procedure to get this done.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I am running out of no of charecters.so I am referring my issue here at link. please refer this for what i did and what is the issue  i am facing.

https://forums.databricks.com/answers/13903/view.html

Answer (score 0):

Each window is based on the Duration. In spark each window is abstracted as `DStream` which nothing but a collection of `RDD's`.

You can convert the RDD to a Dataset/Dataframe and then execute queries using SparkSession.

For example, you can do this

```
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, String.class,
                        String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topics);

JavaDStream<String> invStream = directKafkaStream.map(rdd -> {
        logger.info("Input JSON String ------->" + rdd._2);
        System.out.println("Input JSON String ------->" + rdd._2);
        return rdd._2;
});

invStream.foreachRDD(invrdd -> {
    Dataset<Row> inputDataset = sparkSession.read().json(invrdd);
    inputDataset.createOrReplaceTempView("temptable");
    sparkSession.sql("/write your query");
});
```